# Only return employees who are over 25 from the latest pay period

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-query-store

I have this Query were i only want the employees on the most recent RunID and WHERE they are over 25. As you can see from my results it is returning the employees who are over 25 and THEIR most recent RunID. I only want employees from the last RunID(2131). Next week the RunID will be (2132) and it will be going up every week. Is there a way to only get the employees on the last RunID? Really stuck on this one. Here is a picture from my Query.[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

```
SELECT DISTINCT
ed.EeID,
CONCAT(ed.Forename, '', ed.Surname) AS 'Name',
MAX(pr.RunID)
FROM EeDetails ed
INNER JOIN EeRunBals erb on erb.EeID = ed.EeID
INNER JOIN PayrollRuns pr on pr.RunID = erb.RunID
WHERE ed.BirthDate < '1994-01-01' 
--WHERE pr.RunID = MAX(pr.RunID)
GROUP BY ed.EeID, ed.Forename, ed.Surname, ed.BirthDate
ORDER BY ed.EeId
```

Comment: Please convert your picture to text.

Comment: Please prepare a www.sqlfiddle.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a having clause to filter an aggregated value i.e. max runid. Also you need to use subquery to get the max runid because in the parent query the `MAX(pr.RunID)` is actually max runid of an employee(grouped by) rather than all employees. In your code, you can use the query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
ed.EeID,
CONCAT(ed.Forename, '', ed.Surname) AS 'Name',
MAX(pr.RunID)
FROM EeDetails ed
INNER JOIN EeRunBals erb on erb.EeID = ed.EeID
INNER JOIN PayrollRuns pr on pr.RunID = erb.RunID
WHERE ed.BirthDate < '1994-01-01'     
GROUP BY ed.EeID, ed.Forename, ed.Surname, ed.BirthDate
HAVING MAX(pr.RunID)=(select MAX(RunID) from PayrollRuns)
ORDER BY ed.EeId
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

How about just using aggregation?

```
SELECT ed.EeID, ed.Forename, ed.Surname, ed.BirthDate, MAX(pr.RunId)
FROM EeDetails ed INNER JOIN
     EeRunBals erb 
     ON erb.EeID = ed.EeID INNER JOIN
     PayrollRuns pr 
     ON pr.RunID = erb.RunID
WHERE ed.BirthDate < '1994-01-01' 
GROUP BY ed.EeID, ed.Forename, ed.Surname, ed.BirthDate
ORDER BY ed.EeId;
```

Oh, I see, you don't want the last run id *per person*.  You want the last one overall.  In that case:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES . . . 
FROM EeDetails ed INNER JOIN
     EeRunBals erb 
     ON erb.EeID = ed.EeID INNER JOIN
     PayrollRuns pr 
     ON pr.RunID = erb.RunID
WHERE ed.BirthDate < '1994-01-01' 
ORDER BY pr.RunId DESC;
```

This actually gets the last run id with someone whose birthdate is less than `'1994-01-01'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
DECLARE @MaxRunID = (select MAX(RunID) from PayrollRuns)

   SELECT DISTINCT
        ed.EeID,
        CONCAT(ed.Forename, '', ed.Surname) AS 'Name',
        MAX(pr.RunID)
    FROM EeDetails ed
        INNER JOIN EeRunBals erb on erb.EeID = ed.EeID
        INNER JOIN PayrollRuns pr on pr.RunID = erb.RunID
    WHERE   ed.BirthDate < '1994-01-01' 
        AND pr.RunID = @MaxRunID 
    GROUP BY ed.EeID, ed.Forename, ed.Surname, ed.BirthDate
    ORDER BY ed.EeId
```

Alternatively you can bypass the variable and just place the sub-query instead, though a variable is better.